# What is an XPerf alternative for Linux and Mac OS X?

Tags: linux, macos, software-rec, performance, troubleshooting

XPerf is a tool that allows you to take a detailed trace of various system activity like CPU, I/O and more...

Because of it's detail you can see stack trace counts, disk position offset graphs, driver calls and so on...

Is there a XPerf-a-like alternative for Linux and Mac OS X? What are the top-notch performance tools there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For linux you can combine many tools. top (or htop), iotop, etc. You could also install BSD accounting and use the sa command.

Comment: Some (or all?) of accounting is also available on OS X.

Answer (score 3):

For OS X, look into `dtrace` and derived tools (I think `fs_usage` and `sc_usage` are related; there's also a Linux port), as well as parts of Apple's Developer Tools such as Shark (see e.g. [here](http://developer.apple.com/tools/sharkoptimize.html) and [here](http://developer.apple.com/tools/sharkoptimize.html)).

Comment: Check out [Instruments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruments_(software)) for the new version.

Answer (score 0):

[fseventer](http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software:fseventer:start) is an excellent GUI filesystem monitor for OS X (support until 10.9 Mavericks, 10.10 Yosemite yet unsupported) . It uses the Spotlight API, and often helped me to determine undesired write activities, or determine which config files are indeed read in, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instruments is the closest to xperf

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/PerformanceOverview/PerformanceTools/PerformanceTools.html